# CIDER, how to fix "No cljs REPLs in current session" error

Tags: clojure, cider, nrepl

I'm editing a ClojureScript file, and I have a working ClojureScript REPL in another buffer. But when I try to evaluate a form in my file `ui.cljs`, with `C-c C-c`, I get a beep an a message in the mini-buffer that says

> No cljs REPLs in current session "MyProjectDir/MyProject:localhost:59437

I don't really understand what that means, but it appears that my `ui.cljs` file got associated with the wrong REPL - the Clojure REPL, not the CLJS REPL.

```
CIDER Sessions:

1: MyProjectDir/MyProject:localhost:59437  
    linked-to: buf(ui.cljs)  
      objects: *cider-repl %s(clj)*  

2: MyProjectDir/MyProject:localhost:60016
    linked-to: >proj(~/Workspace/MyProjectDir/MyProject/)  
      objects: *cider-repl %s(cljs:weasel)*
```

I try to "unlink" it by running the `sesman-unlink` command in the `ui.cljs` buffer. But I only get a beep and a cryptic error message in the minibuffer:

> Wrong type argument: stringp, #<buffer ui.cljs>

How to associate that `ui.cljs` file/buffer with the correct REPL?

Emacs 25.3.1 on macOS. CIDER 0.19.0

Comment: How did you start the repl? can you hop between repl and cljs buffer with `C-c C-z`?

Comment: Cider has the command `cider-connect-sibling-cljs` and `cider-connect-sibling-clj` that you can `M-x` in the repl that you want to connect, however I recommend you look at your workflow altogether and use something like `figwheel` or `shadow-cljs`, I can post the way to get it started here if you require so.

Comment: I started 2 REPLs, one with `cider-jack-in` and the other with `cider-jack-in-cljs`, and `weasel` to the first question it asks. It was working well for a while. When it broke, `C-c C-z` was also failing. It seems to have lost the connection between the two and I couldn't recreate it. I don't get `sesman-unlink`. When I have a buffer "linked" it doesn't offer an option to unlink it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed comparison of the different cljs repls to date in [lambdaisland](https://lambdaisland.com/guides/clojure-repls/clojurescript-repls)

Borrowing from this rich and reputable source here is the bits of code you need to have configured for running `weasel`:

**Server (Clojure)**

```
(cljs.repl/repl (weasel.repl.websocket/repl-env :ip "0.0.0.0" :port 9001))
```

**Client (ClojureScript)**

```
(ns main
  (:require [weasel.repl :as repl]))

(when-not (repl/alive?)
  (repl/connect "ws://localhost:9001"))
```

I do recommend using `figwheel` repl. Here is  a video (also by Arne of LambdaIsland) going through the configuration for `Figwheel` with `Cider`:
[link to youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcFx-QL5ySM)

Alternatively [shadow-cljs](http://shadow-cljs.org/) is a different approach complete solution that's easy to configure, repl and all.